# How can i receive some bytes from a device by using bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, byte

i was wondering if any of you can show me a sample of code where im reading some bytes from a device that is sending them through bluetooth.
So far i already did the writing , i mean sending some bytes to the devices , but the device once he read the ones i send , it should send some differend ones .
So the procedure is like this :
I use the app on my phone to connect to the device , and after it is connected i send it an array of bytes . Once he received all of them he has to send me too an array of bytes .

Also do i need a Bluetooth socket Server in order to receive these bytes ?

Any help is more than welcome !
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the procedure and example concerning how to use Bluetooth is here :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Once bluetooth is enabled, one device will act as a server by using `BluetoothServerSocket` object

and the other will use `BluetoothSocket` to act as a client. Then using `myBluetoothServer.accept()` method you will listen to new connection request, the client will try to connect here, and by using streams, read and write you will be fine (check the example on the android website).